# How to deal with unhelpful "correct" answers

Tags: discussion

I've just gotten a little worked up about an answer to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819603/is-this-possible-without-using-recursion?noredirect=1#comment34803413_22819603

Essentially, the op asked

`Is this possible without using recursion?`

and the answer was:

`ANYTHING written using recursion can be re-written to avoid it; it may be difficult, but is always possible.`

Now sure, it's not a particularly good question, but That doesn't excuse an unhelpful answer like that.

---

Now It seems to me that when someone asks `"Is It possible to do X"` they're really asking `"How can I do X"`  I expect other SO users to understand this too.

When someone answers: "Yes, it is possible"  I consider it an non-answer.  It doesn't give the OP what he came here to get, it doesn't help the OP get to where he wants to get, and It won't help future visitors either.

And the worst part is that people normally get rewarded for doing that.  Right now this guy has 2 up-votes.  When I commented as to why I down-voted, multiple people pushed back with "well, the op asked if it was possible".  The fact that these kinds of answers get rewarded makes me briefly feel as though SO has degenerated into some sort of trivia game.

---

I only see this kind of thing once in a blue moon, but it always fills me with anger when I do see it.

Am I the only one who doesn't like these kinds of answers?  It almost seems to be that way considering how they tend to get rewarded.

Comment: I agree that the answer is not helpful but for me the question is just of type *give me the code*. I hope the OP would give that option with a stack a try.

Comment: Downvote the answer, downvote and close the question. Poor questions will breed poor answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a few things:

- Edit the question to make it clear what the user wants ("How do I do this" vs. "Can I do this?")
- Downvote unhelpful answers (that's what the downvote button is for)
- Include your own helpful answer.

If you're feeling especially charitable and lucky, you can leave a comment detailing why you're downvoting.  Sometimes this can turn the focus away from the bad answer to the comments, and that doesn't really solve the problem, so do so with care.

Comment: - Comment on the unhelpful answer explaining why it's not helpful.

Comment: @Servy You can do that too, but as the comments have born out, they often cause a fight.